# msvs12 treats braces as operator()

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void operator()(const char *)
    {
        std::cout << "void operator()(const char *)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;

    a{"hi"};

    return 0;
}
```

msvs12 is happy with this code and I can't understand why. Is it bug or something else?

Update: I tried with msvs 2013 (v12.0.31101.0 Update 4)

Comment: By "VS 12" do you mean "Visual Studio 2012" or do you mean "Dev12" which is "Visual Studio 2013"?

Comment: FWIW, g++ flags a syntax error on the `{`.

Comment: Clang and GCC reject the code, IntelliSense flags it. It looks like a bug. The fact that it's reproducible on the latest version of the [2015 compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) means that you really should report it on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: This doesn't happen in VS2010 and below, it produces the same errors as gcc/clang .. Ran this on a few https://ideone.com/hgNFAk and it worked on VS2012+ .. I think it's a bug in their C++14 user-defined-conversion/brace-initializer-list/overload resolution parsing (if that's any help to MS).. at least best I could see from the C++11/14 references

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is a bug. [Here is the ticket for it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798789/c-vs-2013-rc-allows-to-call-free-functions-using-curly-braces) still opened.